# Should I move from Python 2.7 to 3 when using Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I currently using Python 2.7 for Django. At the moment it goes alright, some models can't be added because it isn't available for 2.7. Only for Python 3.

So, the question is. How much benefit is it to move from 2.7 to 3 now?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is a fair question, but as currently stated it is likely to start opinion-based answers and flamewars.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737326/what-is-the-recommended-version-of-python-for-django-framework

Comment: I am curious to know the models you mentioned that aren't available in Python 2.7

Comment: It will definitely not hurt if you code for compatibility of both versions. You might also want to consider Python2's end of life at 2020.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836375/end-of-support-for-python-2-7

Comment: @itsneo: The model/app that I wanted to add was mezzanine_slideshows. 0.3.2 was not possible, 0.2.1 didn't work properly unfortunately.