# Calculating square root of 2

Tags: python, bisection

Why does the following code does not terminate?

```
# approximating sqrt(2)

def approx (error,left, right):
    c = (left+right)/2
    f = c**2 - 2

    if abs(f)<error :
        return c

    if f < 0:
        left = c
    else:
        right = c

    return approx(error,left,right)

print approx(0.1,0,2)
```

Comment: Try using your debugger: step through the code and see what happens.

Comment: Also: there is no need for recursion here. Just put the body of the code inside `while True:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be losing precision on this line:

```
c = (left+right)/2
```

if `left` and `right` are both integers, then `c` will also be an integer. This leads to unexpected behavior, for instance `1/2` evaluating to `0`.

You can force the result to be a float by dividing by a float:

```
c = (left+right)/2.0
```

Or you can switch to Python 3.X and it will use ordinary sensible division automatically.

Comment: Thank you, this works. This is kind of counter intuitive indeed.

Comment: ... or just import division from future: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/

Comment: @Epsilon integer division floors the result, this is kinda standard programming languages behavior

Comment: @Epsilon "you can switch to Python 3.X and it will use ordinary sensible division automatically". Do that. Python 2 is oooooold.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre At the risk of going off-topic: Python 2.7 is still widely used and has been determined to be [supported until 2020](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836375/end-of-support-for-python-2-7).

Comment: Yes, when you're tied with packages unavailable on python 3 like scapy or opencv, or at work, But for small computationnal programs, it's better to pick the latest standard.