# extracting IP address from text file and use them as input in Python

Tags: python, file-handling

I am currently trying to get ip address from text. But the code I tried is only getting the last line from the file. I am using the following code

```
import paramiko
import time
import getpass
import sys
import socket
import re

user = raw_input("Enter you username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
inp = open(r'ipaddressrouter.txt', 'r') 


for line in inp:
    try:
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh_client.connect(hostname=line,username=user,password=password)
        print "Successful Connection to " + line + '\n'
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('sh ip int b \n')
        output = stdout.read()
        out = open('out.txt', 'a')
        out.write(line + '\n')  
        out.write(output + '\n')
        out.write('\n')
    except (socket.error, paramiko.AuthenticationException):
            status = 'fail' 

ssh_client.close
```

help would be appreciated

Update:

When I removed except

I got the following error

File "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Python Test Scripts\newstest2.py", line 20, in

ssh_client.connect(hostname=host,username=user,password=password)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 329, in connect to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 200, in _families_and_addresses hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM)socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Can some one help me out ?

Comment: what is an example file?

Comment: try using regex to match the string of the ip address pattern

Comment: Its ip address list

Comment: Like 
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2

Comment: 1. How many times do you see `Successful Connection to...`?  Do you see a message for each entry in `ipaddressrouter.txt` or only the last one too? 2. You open the file `out.txt` multiple times but never close it. Try `with open('out.txt', 'a') as out:` 3. You open the file `ipaddressrouter.txt` twice and use only one (and also never close it).

Comment: I only see successful connection message for last one only. I have tried  'with open' () as out:' option too . the result is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
for line in inp:
```

will store the next line of `inp` in `line` *including the terminating new line character* `'\n'`. When you pass this unmodified to `ssh_client.connect()`, then the host name will include `'\n'`. The reason that you get a successful connection with the last line of your input file is very likely that the last line is not terminated by `'\n'`.

One way to remove the `'\n'` is:

```html
line = line.strip()
```

To put it all together, including my comments to your question regarding the recommended use of `with`:

```html
import socket

import paramiko

# get user/password as in the question code (not repeated here)
# ....

status = 'OK'

with open(r'ipaddressrouter.txt', 'r') as inp:
    for line in inp:
        line = line.strip()
        with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh_client:
            ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            try:
                ssh_client.connect(hostname=line, username=user, password=password)
                print("Successful Connection to " + line)
                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('target command here')
                output = stdout.read()
                with open('out.txt', 'a') as out:
                    out.write(line + '\n')
                    out.write(str(output, encoding='utf-8') + '\n')
                    out.write('\n')
            except (socket.error, paramiko.AuthenticationException) as e:
                print("Failed connection to " + line)
                status = 'fail'
```

**Note:**

I modified your example to work with Python3. Some of my changes are probably not necessary for Python2. If you are not forced to use Python2, I would always recommend to use Python3 for new projects. See [End of support for python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4836375)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
lis_of_ip = ['10.1.1.1','10.1.1']
for ip in lis_of_ip:
    if(re.match('((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.|$)){4}', ip)):
        print(ip,'true')
    else:
        print(ip,'false')
```